# What's the problems on this sql command code?

Tags: c#, sql

```
string str = string.Format("SELECT User1.NAME,User1.PORT,User1.IP,File1.SIZE FROM ((SELECT UID,FID FROM [User_File] WHERE FID= {0}) AS a) ,[User1],[File1] WHERE  a.UID= User1.UID AND a.FID=File1.FID", id);

SqlCommand GetTableUsers = new SqlCommand(str, MyConnection);
```

the error is:
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Do we have to decode what do you want to do and what's the error?

Comment: Have you tried this command in your management studio? What error gives on there?

Comment: This seems off-topic for SO, try 'Magicians.SE' instead.

Comment: Before your where clause...  after closing the parentesis here (,[User1],[File1]), just keep [User1] and try from there.

Comment: Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: @gal write teh error into the question and also put into it what you want to know exactly (in this case what the error is about)

Comment: Count the `(`s and `)`. They are not matching.

Comment: @gal: and also you should put into there what id is (what value in a situation where the error occurs)

Comment: @krumia do you see a diferent version than me?  ((SELECT....has 2 closing ) in total. one after FID and one after the AS  else I see no () that isnt closed as well so which ) do you think is missing?

Comment: It looks mostly like the id variable is either not filled or filled with a nonvalid value but for that kogeman would have to post what id is filled with and also put the original (complete original) error message into the question

Comment: @Thomas: All right. My bad. Apologies to OP.

Comment: @krumia no prob there. Took me three times myself to be sure as the sql code is hard to read how it is currently shown in the code tag

Comment: @galkogeman can you also post what the variable id is when you run that part of code? like I said it looks to me as if an empty id variable could cause your problem)

Comment: Try http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm, and one problem is that you have a bracket after the 'as a'. Get rid of one '(' and that one

Comment: As the answer below got accepted I take a guess and you were right about the problem bieng the brackets/subquery @ tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks a bit bulky, I'd recommend you to rewrite it in the following way:

```
     SELECT User1.NAME,User1.PORT,User1.IP,File1.SIZE, 
     FROM [User_File],[User1],[File1] 
     WHERE  [User_File].UID= User1.UID AND [User_File].FID=File1.FID and [User_File].FID = {0}
```

and check if it runs without errors from your SQL Management Studio.